How do I flash LED with signal from 555 timer ONLY when button is pressed?
I am trying to make a circuit in which an LED is off until a button is pressed, and then it flashes with a 1Hz signal from a 555 timer. Currently, its default state is flashing with 1Hz and when the button is pressed it stops flashing and just remains lit.
To further clarify: The R/C/Inverter setup is to debounce the switch. There is a 470Ohm resistor in series with the LED but I forgot to include it in the diagram.
The primary function of the 555 is a clock for a PLD. This is a secondary function that I also need to implement a 1Hz signal for.
Here is my circuit


Please edit the comment about the 555 needing to operate continuously into the question as a constraint. Why is there no series resistor for the LED? What is the intended purpose of the 1k/100nF?

I have edited the post to include this info.

Connect the switch between the output of the Schmidt trigger and the cathode of the LED.

Doing this, the LED still is flashing by default, pushing the button just turns it off. I want the default state to be off and have it flashed when the button is pressed

@ChandlerThornton - Use a normally open switch. While not pushed, the LED is disconnected. Push the button and the LED starts flashing
